# Determining numerical class of divisors inside Jacobian

Tags: algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $g$, let $c$ be a point in $C$. Let $(n_1,\dots, n_{g-1})$ be a $(g-1)$ tuple of nonzero integers.

Consider the image $f_{(n_i)}\colon C^{g-1}\to \mathrm{Pic}^0(C)$ given by 
$$(x_i)\mapsto \mathcal{O}_C\left(\sum n_i(x_i-c)\right),$$
the image $\mathrm{Im}(f_{(n_i)})$ is a divisor in $\mathrm{Pic}^0(C)$.

If $C$ is general, then $NS(C)$ is generated by theta divisor $\Theta$, so we can write numerical  classes as a multiple of the theta divisor,
$$\mathrm{Im}(f_{(n_i)})=d(n_1,\dots,n_{g-1}）\Theta.$$

Is there a reference what are the functions $d$？

(In geometry of algebraic curves vol I, page 223, the case (1,..1,-1,..,-1) was considered, but there seems to be a typo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C_i$ be the image of $C$ by the multiplication map $JC \xrightarrow{\ \times n_i\ }JC$. Your divisor is the image of the addition map $\mu : C_1\times \ldots \times C_{g-1}\rightarrow JC$. Its cohomology class is $(\deg \mu )^{-1}[C_1]*\ldots * [C_{g-1}]$, where "$*$" is the Pontryagin product. Now  the cohomology class $[C_i]\in H^{2g-2}(JC,\mathbb{Z})$ is $n_i^{2}[C]$, so 
$[C_1]*\ldots * [C_{g-1}]=$ $(\prod n_i)^{2}[C]*\ldots * [C]=(\prod n_i)^{2}(g-1)! [\Theta ]\ $ .

Therefore $d(n_1,\ldots ,n_{g-1})=(\prod n_i)^{2}\dfrac{(g-1)!}{\deg \mu }\,\cdot $

The remaining problem is to compute $\deg \mu $. I believe that if
$n_1=\ldots =n_a<n_{a+1}=\ldots =n_{a+b}< n_{a+b+1}=\ldots $, we have $\deg \mu =a!b!\ldots $, but this should be checked.